# Why does debsums show libgcc_s.so.1 as "replaced" and what should be done about it?

Tags: debian, security, gcc

On Debian11/KDE `debsums | grep -v OK` showed `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` as `REPLACED`. "Replaced" means that "The file has been replaced by a file from a different package."

This isn't how things are supposed to be so how can one find out why (e.g. by which package) it was replaced? What should be done about this?

`sha256sum /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` returns `2d771c2e232fce107c7ec7f9a64b9a804e6d6737063088a2d8096b149a0af8cd`.

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1`?

Comment: @muru it's `libgcc-s1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1`. I don't think it could have been caused by running `CXX="gcc" cmake ..` and most of the time permissions are set to `sudo chmod 0444 /usr/bin/gcc`. Apper shows `libgcc` was installed only years ago (via it?). I also ran `grep -rnisI "gcc" /var/log/dpkg.log*` which only shows that `linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86:amd64` was installed during the recent Debian upgrade. However, for bad reasons the dpkg.log files seem to be incomplete (but that's a separate issue).

Comment: The file itself is fine, the checksum matches the canonical version in Debian 11 currently.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Debian 11 amd64 system. Here's how I fixed it.

Search for the file here:

```shell
grep -Hin libgcc_s.so.1 /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums
```

On my system two packages were found: `libgcc-s1:amd64` and `libgcc1:amd64`. `libgcc1` is from an older Debian version and no longer is available from Debian 11's repository.

It turned out to be related to an older gcc version that was still installed, but which I no longer needed.

Found by searching for all packages which are no longer available from repository:

```shell
comm -23 --nocheck-order <(awk '/^Package: / {print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | sort) <(awk '/^Package: / {print $2}' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages | sort)
```

After removing `gcc-8-base:amd64` and `libgcc1:amd64` the debsums `REPLACED` message was gone.